# Finding and updating obj in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I find an object in the array "friends" with the id "5b6ef34cf2b0c73490d9f742" in the document with the id "5b6ef33ff2b0c73490d9f741" and update its "favorite" key?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b6ef33ff2b0c73490d9f741"
    },
    "friends": [
        {
            "id": "5b6ef34cf2b0c73490d9f742",
            "favorite": false
        },
        {
            "id": "5b6ef34cf2b0c73490d9f743",
            "favorite": false
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b6ef33ff2b0c73490d9f745"
    },
    "friends": [
        {
            "id": "5b6ef34cf2b0c73490d9f742",
            "favorite": false
        },
        {
            "id": "5b6ef34cf2b0c73490d9f744",
            "favorite": false
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **`update`** with **`$set`**

```
model.update({"_id":'5b6ef33ff2b0c73490d9f741'}, {$set: {"friends.$.favorite": "true""}})
```

Comment: This only works if I have 1 document in the collection, but when there are two or more it will update the 1st one.